# module.exports montar um array com os dados da api

Tags: array, node.js, express.js

Bom eu estou com o seguinte problema é não to conseguindo de forma alguma resolver.

Bem eu tenho um script config.js

```
module.exports = {
    "adsense": {
        "bloco728x90": {
            "google_ad_client": "ca-pub-x",
            "google_ad_slot": 00
        }
    },
};
```

Só que essas informação eu queria pegar na api **localhost/api/adsense** é montar o array com os dados recebido.

Usando o `http.get()` eu consigo lista os dados recebido , só não to conseguindo usar o `http.get` junto com o `module.exports` pra montar o config.js sem precisar de ficar editando o arquivo toda vez que eu atualizar a informação na api.

Answer (score 0):

Tem um pacote no node que é justamente pra isso.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

Você passa o contexto do ambiente e ele te fornece as config certas.

Espero ter ajudado